# Exported service does not require permission: what does it mean?

Tags: android, android-service

I created a service that is bound by other applications through AIDL, and I add it to the manifest as follows:

```
<service android:name=".MyService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.example.android.myservicedemo.IService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

where IService is the AIDL interface.

In this way, Eclipse show me the warning *Exported service does not require permission*. If I remove the `intent-filter`, the warning disappear, but obviously the applications are unable to bind to the service.

What does this warning mean?

Comment: It means that other (arbitrary) applications the user has on his phone can bind to your `Service` and call whatever method they please that is exposed through your AIDL interface.

Comment: create a new [<permission>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) in your AndroidManifest.xml and use the name of that as the `android:permission` attribute of your `<service>` declaration. Or just ignore the warning - what is the service intended to do? If you are fine with keeping the service "internal" it's much easier just to set `android:exported="false"` on your `<service>`

Comment: @Jens: It is a service that can be bound by external applications.

Comment: Then either ignore the warning or add a <permission>, use "signature" if they're all your own applications signed with the same certificate or just go with "normal" otherwise.

Comment: @Jens: I'm just using "normal". In order to use "signature", should I create a certificate?

Comment: You're already using a (release) certificate to sign your applications - the signature protection checks that the application requesting the permission is same-signed as the application that defined the permission.

Comment: @Jens Thanks...it helped me.... btw you can add your comments as answer. Let enzom83 accept it.

Comment: But what about Receivers? A receiver that listens for PACKAGE_ADDED broadcasts should declare which permission to be required? The broadcast is sent by the system and setting android:exported=false would not allow the receiver to listen for system broadcasts... I don't think that the Lint warning doesn't make much sense.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462936/exported-activity-does-not-require-permission-when-attempting-to-launch-from-a/11526028#11526028 (possible duplicate)

Comment: Well, what if I don't *care* that other applications can access my service? What if I want to export it to everybody?

Answer (score 136):

I had the same issue when I **updated SDK** to version **20**. I removed it adding **android:exported** property  `android:exported="false"` like so:

```
<service android:name=".MyService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.example.android.myservicedemo.IService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

See this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: it's not a fix, `exported="false"` means that your service can't be used outside other apps. So you just change functionality. It's not an answer

Answer (score 65):

If you want to restrict you activity usage to your own application, then you should add `exported=false` to your activity's manifest statement.

If you want to allow other applications to use it (explicitly through its class name or, better, by using an intent with a data type or action) then you have two choices :

- restrict those applications by using a permission
- allow all applications to use it, then you can add `tools:ignore="ExportedActivity"` to your activity's manifest statement.

--

Same reasonning applies to a service, with `tools:ignore="ExportedService"` and content providers with `tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider"`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!! However, notice that this requires to *add* a xmlns declaration at the top of the manifest file: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Comment: Thanks, its added automatically by Eclipse. That's a nice complement for other IDEs users.

Comment: I use Eclipse 4.2.1, and it doesn't add it, giving an error (at least with the default config?). It just says: `The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:ignore" associated with an element type "activity" is not bound`, and no choices are given for fixing this.

Comment: It will add it if you remove your tools:foo=bar statement, then when there is an error / warning, right click and use a quick fix to add the tools statement.

Comment: This is what I meant: eclipse gives no quick fix for this error.

Comment: @Snicolas Your answer should be the accepted answer, damnit! It would have saved me some time, since I looked over so many different answers for this. This is perfect, but I would highly recommend including the part about adding `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` as Eclipse would not add this for me, either. It was a pain to figure out. Also, I'm a little stupid, but I didn't know it was literally `tools:ignore="ExportedActivity"`, so I tried putting in my `Activity`s identifier. Oops! ;) Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Can you please point me to the correct direction to "restrict those applications by using a permission"?

Comment: Special case is the SyncService, which should be exported but you only want the system to use it. For SyncService or AuthenticatorService add android:permission="signature"

Answer (score 4):

As [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967142/jens) said, "It means that other (arbitrary) applications the user has on his phone can bind to your Service and call whatever method they please that is exposed through your AIDL interface."