# How do I make a class to behave as an app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, default, viewer

I made an image viewer that has 3 activities:

1) Main: where I search for files using regexp against filenames. The result is an ArrayList called 'files' that is sent using Extras to...

2) Thumbs: Through Extras it gets the filenames, and shows a grid with thumbnails (already stored locally). When you click a thumbnail, the position and 'files' is sent to...

3) Photo: It shows files(position) fullscreen.

Now, I want to make 'Photo' my default image viewer. I know how to call the class from another app. But is is possible to make 'Photo' the default viewer just by clicking an image, without calling the whole app?

Comment: **without calling the whole app?** - I don't understand the question, what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Squonk: Yes. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest under your "Photo" image viewer activity add the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

You'll need to get the URI of the image from within the intent to display it.

Comment: When I click in an image, I still get `No application can perform this action` (I've disabled the Gallery app). Moreover, I got a warning on the manifest file: `Exported activity does not require permission`.

Comment: I forgot the category.. Try the updated XML with the category added. you can set your activity to not be exported by setting 'android:exported="false"' in the <activity> tag

Comment: Great, this looks alive now... Just one more question, please: How do I _get the URI of the image from within the intent to display it_? I tried adding a method `public Photo(Uri uri) { ... }` inside the Photo class, without success... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: In your activity that gets opened in the onCreate / onResume (basically anywhere in the activity) you can call Uri uri = getIntent().getData();  and that will give you the URI of the image

Comment: Two problems: first, the thing crashed with a `Permission denial` exception due to the lack of export. So I deleted the line, and kept the warning. But at least I get something now. Problem is that I get as uri.getPath() the following: `/external/images/media/119275`. Not even directory `/external` exists! :( But at least Photo opens without errors. Thanks for your patience...

Comment: How are you trying to display the image?

Comment: With a `img.setImageBitmap(new BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename))`, where `img` is a `TouchImageView`. The thing opens, but the problem is that the uri path is incorrect. Don't know why...

Comment: The Uri you are provided isn't a file path Uri. It's a Uri that's to be used with content providers (databases). Trying calling img.setImageURI(uri);

Comment: Funny. For some images, it works. These images have uri `file://...`. Some images don't work, and those have uris like `content://media/external/images/media/119289`. Still, the folder contains only JPEGs... Maybe "My Files" app is sending wrong data to my app when I click an image?? EDIT: Mmmm... I see... Will try that. THANKS!!!!!!!!!

Comment: BTW, to fix the warning I used this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12217347/1483390]